# Rails ActiveRecord string field encoding vs Ruby String encoding

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, character-encoding, rails-activerecord

## Context: Transcoding a string from an external source for saving in the database

From a gem, I get a string `s` that has `latin-1`-encoded content and that I want to store in a Rails model.

```
r = MyRecord.new(mystring: s)
# ...
r.save
```

Because my PostgreSQL database uses `UTF-8` encoding, saving the model after setting its string field to the string causes an error when that string contains certain non-ASCII characters:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::CharacterNotInRepertoire: ERROR:  invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0xdf 0x65
...
```

I can solve this easily by transcoding the string:

```
r = MyRecord.new(mystring: s.encode(Encoding::UTF_8, Encoding::ISO_8859_1))
# ...
r.save
```

(Because `r.encoding` returns *`#<Encoding:ASCII-8BIT>`* instead of *`#<Encoding:ISO-8859-1>`*, I'm [passing the source encoding as the second argument](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/String.html#method-i-encode). The gem that produced `s` probably isn't aware that the file it read the string from is `latin1` encoded.)

## Challenge: Avoid hard-coding the destination encoding

It occurred to me, that knowledge about the database's string encoding does not belong in the part of the code where I do this persisting and thus also the transcoding.

I can ask the model's class for the database's encoding:

```
MyRecord.connection.encoding
```

This doesn't return a [Ruby `Encoding`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Encoding.html) object though, it returns a string containing the encoding's name. Fortunately, the `Encoding` class [can be queried with names](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Encoding.html#method-c-find) (and [some aliases](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Encoding.html#method-i-names)) to look up encodings:

```
Encoding.find 'UTF-8' # returns #<Encoding:UTF-8>, the value of Encoding::UTF_8
```

Unfortunately, **different naming conventions are used:** `MyRecord.connection.encoding` returns `'UTF8'` (**no** minus sign) while `Encoding.find(...)` needs to be passed `'UTF-8'` (**with** minus sign) or `'CP65001'` if we want it to return *`#<Encoding:UTF-8>`*.)

Sooooo close.

## Question: Is there a clean and/or recommended way

**to avoid the hard-coding of the destination encoding and instead dynamically determine and use the the database's encoding for that?**

### Discarded ideas

I don't feel doing string manipulation or pattern matching on the result of `MyRecord.connection.encoding` or on the contents of [`Encoding.aliases()`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Encoding.html#method-c-aliases) would be any better than just leaving the hard-coded values in the code.

Modifying `Encoding.aliases()`'s return value doesn't have any effect:

```
Encoding.aliases['UTF8'] = 'UTF-8'
Encoding.find 'UTF8' # ArgumentError: unknown encoding name - UTF8
```

(and doesn't feel right either, anyway), nor does modifying the return value of [`#names`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Encoding.html#method-i-names):

```
Encoding::UTF_8.names.push('UTF8')
Encoding.find 'UTF8'# ArgumentError: unknown encoding name - UTF8
```

I guess both only return dynamically generated collections or copies of the underlying collections, and for a good reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest and, arguably, cleanest solution to this problem would be to not call `Encoding.find` directly, but have an utility method (perhaps in a module located at `lib/yourapp`) which knows about the encoding name differences you care about and falls back to `Encoding.find` for all other inputs:

```
module YourApp
  module DatabaseStringEncoding
    def find(name)
      case name
      when 'UTF8'
        Encoding::UTF_8
      ...
      else
        Encoding.find(name)
      end 
    end
  end
```

This is both easy to understand and discover (as opposed to modifying `Encoding` directly, which is not visible to the reader of the code which does the encoding). Based on such a `find` method, you could then go further and implement a method which automatically recodes a string to the database's string encoding using `YourRecord.connection.encoding`.

I know it would be more exciting to get `Encoding.find` to do exactly what you want, but I would argue that this "dumber" approach would actually be the better one. :-)